# No Video Played in DirectShow MSDN Example

Tags: c++, video-streaming, directshow, video-processing

I'm trying to go through the DirectShow documentation provided on MSDN. I'm a relative beginner to C++, as well. I was on the first example code in the DirectShow documentation here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd389098(v=vs.85).aspx
I followed along, modified the file string to point to a video on my own computer, included  and added the strmiids.lib library as a reference. My code builds successfully, and the Console Window appears. But that's it. No video renders. 
I'm using VS2015, on a Windows 8.1 laptop, and I have the Windows SDK installed as well. That's where i got the strmiids.lib file. 
Any help would be awesome, as this has been a frustrating obstacle in the way of learning DirectShow programming.
Thanks!

Comment: Have you done the error handling correctly? You need to check the `hr` value after every call! (`if (FAILED(hr))`) And what kind of video do you try to play? Maybe you don't have the right codecs for it.

Comment: The file is a .mp4. DirectShow should be able to handle mp4 files, right? And the code was taken directly from MSDN website, so shouldn't it just work? I don't see the point of providing an example that doesn't work...

Comment: No DirectShow has  no defeult Support for MP4 files. You  need to install a multiplexer for this. Like the Haali  Media Splitter.